# Webdriver HTML missing in list of found elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm retrieving a list of elements and then looping through to find an element inside each. The first 15 items work as normal, but every one after that (217 in total) I run into an issue. I found that this try and except:

```py
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
sleep(5)

links = []
for card in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-card-grid__item-1-2'):
    try:
        link = card.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute("href")
        links.append(link)
    except:
        print(len(links))
        print(card.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Outputs repeatedly:

```py
15
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
15
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
15
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
15
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
```

Looking at the page's HTML each div element I retrieve is has the same format

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a>
```

But this changes after the 15th item when using webdriver. I assigned the retrieved elements and sliced to see the change that takes place after the 15th item.

```py
cards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-card-grid__item-1-2')
cards_slice = cards[0:20]
for card in cards_slice:
    print(card.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Output:

```html
...
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"><div id="product680985002"><div class="product-card__image-wrapper"><a href="https://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=680985002&amp;cid=1173813&amp;pcid=1149858&amp;vid=1&amp;nav=hamnav%3AMen%3A%3AResponsibly-Made%20Shop&amp;grid=pds_13_217_1" target="_self" aria-hidden="false" class="css-0"><img alt="The Gen Good T-Shirt" src="https://www4.assets-gap.com/webcontent/0020/057/840/cn20057840.jpg" class="product-card__image" productid="680985002" productname="The Gen Good T-Shirt"><div style="box-sizing: border-box;"><div class="imgOverlayWrapper"><img class="imgInnerWrapper" src="/Asset_Archive/AllBrands/Iconography/gen_good_overlay_icon.svg" alt="overlay image"></div></div></a></div></div><a class="product-card__link" href="https://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=680985002&amp;cid=1173813&amp;pcid=1149858&amp;vid=1&amp;nav=hamnav%3AMen%3A%3AResponsibly-Made%20Shop&amp;grid=pds_13_217_1"><div class="product-card__name">The Gen Good T-Shirt</div></a><div class="product-card__body"><div class="product-card-price"><div><span><span class="">$19.00</span></span></div></div><div class="product-card__marketing-flag">This Style Does Good. Excluded From Promotions.</div></div></div></div>
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"><div id="product680985012"><div class="product-card__image-wrapper"><a href="https://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=680985012&amp;cid=1173813&amp;pcid=1149858&amp;vid=1&amp;nav=hamnav%3AMen%3A%3AResponsibly-Made%20Shop&amp;grid=pds_14_217_1" target="_self" aria-hidden="false" class="css-0"><img alt="The Gen Good T-Shirt" src="https://www3.assets-gap.com/webcontent/0020/046/627/cn20046627.jpg" class="product-card__image" productid="680985012" productname="The Gen Good T-Shirt"><div style="box-sizing: border-box;"><div class="imgOverlayWrapper"><img class="imgInnerWrapper" src="/Asset_Archive/AllBrands/Iconography/gen_good_overlay_icon.svg" alt="overlay image"></div></div></a></div></div><a class="product-card__link" href="https://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=680985012&amp;cid=1173813&amp;pcid=1149858&amp;vid=1&amp;nav=hamnav%3AMen%3A%3AResponsibly-Made%20Shop&amp;grid=pds_14_217_1"><div class="product-card__name">The Gen Good T-Shirt</div></a><div class="product-card__body"><div class="product-card-price"><div><span><span class="">$19.00</span></span></div></div><div class="product-card__marketing-flag">This Style Does Good. Excluded From Promotions.</div></div></div></div>
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
<div class="product-card-grid__inner"><div class="product-card"></div></div>
...
```

Update: after trying the exact same first code again, I'm now only getting a link from the first 8 elements?

I would understand if, since I'm scrolling to the bottom, that only the bottom elements are loading, but why is it the case that it's only the first?

Comment: whats the url? can you share that?

Comment: @chitown88 https://www.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=1149858&nav=hamnav%3AMen%3A%3AResponsibly-Made%20Shop#pageId=0&department=75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `len(links)` outside of the loop, let it finish, and found that some additional elements were actually found after the exceptions. Looking at the links retrieved shows me that links are retrieved from the top and , contrary to what I thought, some are retrieved from the bottom elements--but still not most of the middle ones.

The issue is likely that just scrolling to the bottom doesn't load all of the middle elements/keep them loaded since it's a long page. But the first elements stay loaded. I'm thinking I need to slowly scroll to the bottom to load everything.

**Confirmed.** I got it to work by scrolling down a bit at a time, which loaded all of the elements fully.